# Joomla 3.8 Administration - direct link to to enable/disable module

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, module

I have googled bud did not found answer.
Howto in joomla Administration create a button do Enable/disable any module to show/hide on frontend?
eg. I'm in restaurant component and I need to use 2-3 buttons to change delivery time in frontend. e. 30 minutes, 60 minutes etc. I will create 2-3 different modules with own text and I need to show/hide them directly form my restaurant component using one click button in this component.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on the front-end of the website, logged in, and on a restaurant component page. You have different modules that reveal text ie. 30 min, 60 min.

Your challenge is that it takes too long to open each module and enable/disable when you are busy filling orders.

Option #1:
I would have someone write a plugin that ties together all delivery modules. Use a dropdown menu (30 min, 60 min, etc.) so that you can turn on what you need quickly. A button would require an additional step because you would click on it, another screen would open up, then you pick the module to show.

Option #2
Try installing "Modules Anywhere" from Regular Labs. It's free and just may do the trick. After a quick install and set-up, you basically use a shortcode containing the name of module to show up.

Just create a single (Custom HTML) module, put it on the front end at your restaurant module and use the shortcode below to point from 30 minutes to 60 minutes, etc. Be sure that all of your delivery modules are published; make the module names easy (ie. 30min).

```
 {module Name of My Module}
 {module 30min}
  Quickly changes to {module 60min}
```

It's not a button, but it's quick enough to do the job.
https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modulesanywhere

Good luck!